# Convert a string which contains an array of json objects to an array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a variable which is a string of JSON, this JSON is an array of objects:

`String actions = "[{'title': 'BBC', 'url': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk'}, {'title': 'GOOGLE', 'url': 'https://www.google.com'}]"`

I need to convert this into some thing that I can use within my android app, so an array or object that I can iterate over. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Gson

```
String actions = "[{'title': 'BBC', 'url': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk'}, {'title': 'GOOGLE', 'url': 'https://www.google.com'}]";

List list = new Gson().fromJson(actions, List.class);
```

If your JSON has known structure you can map it to class, for example:

```
class Website {
        String title;
        String url;
}


Type type = new TypeToken<List<Website>>() {}.getType();
List<Website> list = new Gson().fromJson(actions, type);
```

Comment: Results in `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0` error.

Comment: What is your Gson version? Did you test above code for other input, than provided?

Comment: The actual string that I am passing is: `[{"title":"GOOGLE","url":"https://www.google.com"}]` this comes from an API. My Gson version is 2.7

Comment: I checked code and it works in both scenarios, with version 2.7. Are you shure that "new Gson().fromJson(actions,..." throws exception?

Comment: Oh, I take back everything I said, it looks as though it was my Log causing that error.

Comment: This works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `org.json.JSONArray` for that.

```
String actions = "[{'title': 'BBC', 'url': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk'}, {'title': 'GOOGLE', 'url': 'https://www.google.com'}]" 

JSONArray actionArray = new JSONArray(actions)
for(int x = 0; x < actionArray.length; x++ ){
    JSONAobject obj = actionArray.getJSONObject(x);
    String title = obj.optString("title");
    //Other code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In java, you can use json library for this purpose:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: There's not need for use external library because Java has buildin class for that.

Comment: Cool. but that does not mean that  my answer is  incorrect. Why have you  voted  it  down?

Comment: i have not voted down